# Multiple page sequences and page numbers

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using XSLT and XSL-FO for document creation.

I need to introduce multiple sequences of page numbering, i.e main section numbered from 1 to end page, which is broken by two subsequences of corresponding subdocuments, numbered from 1 to end of each of these sections, and after them the main sequence is continued.

The problem I can't overcome is that the subsequences are counted in main sequence, and page number of main section after continuation is incremented page number of previous subsequence.

So I get e.g.

| main section | subsection | subsection | continuation of main |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, 2, 3 | 1, 2 | 1, 2 | 3, 4, 5... |

And I want

| main section | subsection | subsection | continuation of main |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, 2, 3 | 1, 2 | 1, 2 | 4, 5, 6... |

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should really show an example of the FO markup which produces wrongly-numbered pages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In an FO file, the `fo:page-sequence` elements define a *flat* list of contents to be paginated, so there is no concept of a "main section" containing "subsections".

The [initial-page-number](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#initial-page-number) property controls how page numbers are computed for a page sequence.
In particular, when a page sequence ends and a new one starts the only available options concerning page numbering are:

- continue the enumeration with the next page number (optionally, the next odd one or even one)
- restart from a specified number

There is no way to refer to a different page sequence and say "continue from *that*".

---

That said, if your document is not much more complicated than your example you can achieve what you want with a **workaround**.

This is probably the easiest (and dirtiest) one:

1. create the pdf output without changing anything; note down the page number that the "continuation of main" section should start from (4, in your example)
2. modifiy the FO file (or the XSLT), inserting `initial-page-number="4"` in the appropriate `fo:page-sequence`
3. recreate the output file

Slightly more complicated:

1. modify your XSLT so that it produces the `fo:page-sequence` elements in the order: (main section) - (continuation of main) - (subsection) - (subsection)
   there is no need to specify `initial-page-number` for the "continuation of main" section; for subsections, use `initial-page-number="1"` to restart the page numbers (but they are already like this, from your example)
2. once you have the pdf, use some tool to move the pages around and have them in the order you desire

A cleaner and fully-automated solution would require using [FOP's intermediate format](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.7/intermediate.html):

1. create the intermediate format output
2. modify it to fix the page numbers as needed
3. create the final output from the modified intermediate file

---

**A final note:** you did not specify *why* your document needs such a peculiar page numbering and what degree of control you have on this requirement, but I cannot help wondering whether it is confusing for a reader to see page numbers restart that way, and difficult for them to find what they need ("I am told the information I need is on page 2; but *which* page 2?").

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately, I can't apply any of your solutions on my own because:
1.: I simplified the example above and these "subsections" can vary in length
2. and 3.: I am not responsible enough for this project to be able to apply them.
Nevertheless I will suggest team responsible for this using the second solution.